# Replace a table using Rmysql and keeping all table structure

Tags: r, rmysql

I am new to Rmysql and can´t update a table without losing its stucture.

I was using

```
RMySQL::dbWriteTable(mydb, "table",table, overwrite = TRUE, row.names = FALSE )
```

But I noted that I lose all the indexes and also lose variable types...

For example: "decimal" variables became "double"

At phpmyadmin I would truncate and upload the update...

How could I do it using Rmysql?

Comment: IN some other packages, there is `dbSendUpdate`

Comment: What about deleting table `DELETE FROM table` and then append (not overwrite) df?